# How to track events of an activity from another class in android?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am trying to track an event (`OnActivityResult`) from another class by creating an interface in the Activity and implementing that interface in that class. Like this:

```
OnAuthCompletedListener listener;

public void setOnAuthCompletedListener(OnAuthCompletedListener listener){
      this.listener = listener;  
}

public interface OnAuthCompletedListener {
     void OnAuthCompleted(Auth auth)
}
```

and In Another class I wrote

```
MainActivity activity= new MainActivity();
activity.setOnAuthCompletedListener(auth->{

});
```

But whenever the event occurs the app crashes with a NPE. I understand I am using different activity instance that the real one. My question is how can I use that interface in a non activity class?

I also know that there is some better solution using RXJava, but I am not smart enough to implement that, can anyone help?

Comment: your "another class" should get real working `Activity` reference instead of `new` one

Comment: how to achieve that?

Comment: well, maybe introduce new method `public void setActivityForListener(Activity act)` or just show your "another class", it would be easier to write answer

Comment: well, for official reason I can't show the class but It is a provider class with no reference of any context or activity in that class.

Comment: well, without code its hard to guess which resolution will fit your need. but I've posted some basic way as answer, check this out

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume "another class"

```
public class AnotherClass implements OnAuthCompletedListener {

    // rest of code

    public void OnAuthCompleted(Auth auth){
        //interface implementation 
    }

}
```

Declare `ArrayList<OnAuthCompleted> registeredInterfaces = new ArrayList<>();` in `Activity` and register its listener in array every time when you create new instance of class which `implements OnAuthCompletedListener` (so in this example: `AnotherClass`, but you can have multiple different classes implementing this interface)

```
AnotherClass newAnotherClass = new AnotherClass(); 
registeredInterfaces.add(newAnotherClass);
```

when you are `null`ing/destroying this `newAnotherClass` instance then unregister its listener

```
newAnotherClass.destroy();
registeredInterfaces.remove(newAnotherClass);
newAnotherClass = null;
```

now when `OnAuthCompletedListener` is called in `Activity` then iterate through this array and call every registered `OnAuthCompletedListener.OnAuthCompleted`. and don't forget to clear this array when `Activity` is destroyed, just to be sure that there is no memory leak

Comment: I have taken a MainActivity instance in my Application class and initialized it in onCreate() then in the AnotherClass I didn't take new instance of that Activity instead I have used
MyApplication.getInstance().mainActivity.setOnAuthCompletedListener. Now NP Exception is not occuring and solved the problem, but is this a godd approach?

Comment: well, this is very questionable... `MyApplication.getInstance()` isn't clean and reliable workaround, in some cases it may return `null`, but when you work only with `Activities` then it will work. read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-in-android) post and all answers carefully incuding comments for more info